# Parsing Character String in R with "\r\n" from PDF Conversion

Tags: r, string, parsing, pdf, stringr

I am having issues parsing the following character string in R:

```
> dput(txt[1])
"NATIONAL BASKETBALL ASSOCIATION                                                                                                  OFFICIAL SCORER'S REPORT\r\n                                                                                                                                                      FINAL BOX\r\nWednesday, January 17, 2018 Spectrum Center, Charlotte, NC\r\nOfficials: #15 Zach Zarba, #11 Derrick Collins, #12 CJ Washington\r\n                                                                                                                                                Game Duration: 2:14\r\n                                                                                                                                                 Attendance: 11528\r\nVISITOR: Washington Wizards (25-20)\r\n                                                    POS       MIN         FG FGA 3P 3PA FT FTA OR DR TOT A PF ST                                 TO  BS    +/- PTS\r\n22  Otto Porter Jr.                                   F      22:45         2      6      1       3        1       2       0    2    2  2 0 0      0   0   -24   6\r\n 5  Markieff Morris                                   F      15:26         1      5      0       2        0       0       0    5    5  1 4 0      1   0   -10   2\r\n13  Marcin Gortat                                     C      19:42         0      3      0       0        0       2       3    5    8  1 2 2      0   0   -23   0\r\n 3  Bradley Beal                                      G      27:43        10 19          4       6        2       2       1    2    3  2 1 0      5   1   -14   26\r\n 2  John Wall                                         G      24:20         5     11      2       2        0       0       0    2    2  9 2 0      3   2   -20   12\r\n30  Mike Scott                                               25:13 7             10      2       2        2       2       0    2    2  3  3   1 0     0    -8   18\r\n12  Kelly Oubre Jr.                                          26:32 5              9      3       5        3       4       0    5    5  0  4   0 3     0     3   16\r\n28  Ian Mahinmi                                              08:47 1              2      0       0        2       2       0    1    1  2  1   0 0     1    -1   4\r\n31  Tomas Satoransky                                         25:49 2              3      0       0        2       2       1    2    3  7  1   0 1     0   -13   6\r\n20  Jodie Meeks                                              20:17 2              3      1       2        2       3       1    4    5  0  0   0 2     0   -10   7\r\n14  Jason Smith                                              13:50 4              8      0       0        2       2       1    2    3  3  5   0 1     2     0   10\r\n 1  Chris McCullough                                         06:48 1              3      0       1        0       0       0    1    1  0  0   0 0     1    -1   2\r\n 8  Tim Frazier                                              02:48 0              0      0       0        0       2       0    0    0  1  0   0 0     0     1   0\r\n                                                            240:00 40            82     13      23       16      23       7   33   40 31 23   3 16    7   -24  109\r\n                                                                           48.8%         56.5%             69.6%           TM REB: 7     TOT TO: 16 (20 PTS)\r\nHOME: CHARLOTTE HORNETS (18-25)\r\n                                                    POS       MIN         FG FGA 3P 3PA FT FTA OR DR TOT A PF ST                                 TO  BS    +/- PTS\r\n14  Michael Kidd-Gilchrist                            F      22:59         8     11      0       0        5       6       0    4    4  2 1 3      0   0    26   21\r\n 2  Marvin Williams                                   F      21:38         4      7      3       4        1       1       1    2    3  1 0 0      1   0    25   12\r\n12  Dwight Howard                                     C      28:54         7     13      0       0        4       5       3   12 15 2 2 2         2   2    17   18\r\n 5  Nicolas Batum                                     G      26:00         4      8      2       4        1       2       0    3    3  4 1 1      2   0    17   11\r\n15  Kemba Walker                                      G      28:48         6     15      4       8        3       3       1    2    3  7 1 0      1   1    14   19\r\n 3  Jeremy Lamb                                              21:02 7              9      2       2        0       0       3    0    3  0  4   0   0   1    -4   16\r\n44  Frank Kaminsky                                           23:36 6             14      1       4        1       1       0    2    2  2  1   1   0   0    -5   14\r\n10  Michael Carter-Williams                                  15:12 0              2      0       1        3       4       0    3    3  5  2   0   0   1     8   3\r\n 8  Johnny O'Bryant III                                      19:07 2              6      1       2        2       2       3    3    6  1  1   1   2   0     7   7\r\n21  Treveon Graham                                           22:00 3              6      1       2        2       2       2    2    4  1  4   1   1   0     7   9\r\n 1  Malik Monk                                               03:59 1              5      1       3        0       0       0    1    1  1  0   1   0   0     2   3\r\n 7  Dwayne Bacon                                             03:59 0              2      0       1        0       0       0    0    0  0  0   0   0   0     2   0\r\n32  Julyan Stone                                             02:46 0              0      0       0        0       0       0    2    2  1  1   0   0   0     4   0\r\n                                                            240:00 48            98     15      31       22      26      13   36   49 27 18  10   9   5    24  133\r\n                                                                             49%         48.4%             84.6%           TM REB: 7     TOT TO: 10 (15 PTS)\r\nSCORE BY PERIOD 1                    2       3       4     FINAL\r\n               Wizards 36           25      18      30        109\r\n            HORNETS 38              39      25      31        133\r\nInactive: Wizards - Mac (Injury/Illness - left achilles surgery), Robinson (G League Team - two-way player)\r\nInactive: Hornets - Mathiang, Paige (G League Team - two-way player), Zeller (Injury/Illness - left knee surgery)\r\nPoints in the Paint: Wizards 30 (15/27), HORNETS 50 (25/48)                                Biggest Lead: Wizards 2, HORNETS 28\r\n2nd Chance Points: Wizards 9 (4/7), HORNETS 21 (6/12)                                      Lead Changes: 2\r\nFast Break Points: Wizards 16 (6/8), HORNETS 10 (5/8)                                      Times Tied: 5\r\nTechnical fouls - Individual\r\nWizards (3): Wall 4:16 1st , Brooks 6:49 2nd , Frazier 4:00 4th\r\nHORNETS (2): Kidd-Gilchrist 3:08 2nd , Carter-Williams 4:00 4th\r\nTechnical fouls - Defensive Three Seconds\r\nWizards (0) : NONE\r\nHORNETS (1) : Howard 2:27 1st\r\nEjections\r\nWizards (1): Frazier 4:00 4th\r\nHORNETS (1): Carter-Williams 4:00 4th\r\nMEMO: Ejected for excessive communication and contact during stoppage in play.\r\nMEMO: Ejected for excessive communication and contact during stoppage in play.\r\n                                                         Copyright (c ) 2017-2018 NBA Properties, INC. All Rights Reserved\r\n"
```

I would like to extract the following sub-section of the above character string:

```
Technical fouls - Individual\r\nWizards (3): Wall 4:16 1st , Brooks 6:49 2nd , Frazier 4:00 4th\r\nHORNETS (2): Kidd-Gilchrist 3:08 2nd , Carter-Williams 4:00 4th\r\nTechnical fouls - Defensive Three Seconds\r\nWizards (0) : NONE\r\nHORNETS (1) : Howard 2:27 1st\r\n
```

To do this, I have tried different variations of the following approach:

```
library(stringr)
> techs <- str_extract(txt[1], "(?<=\\bTechnical).+?.(\\\r\nEjections)")
> techs
[1] NA
```

But, as you can see, it doesn't work. This approach has worked successfully in other sections of the character string. Like here, for example:

```
> str_extract(txt[1], "(?<=\\bInactive).+?.(\\\r\nPoints)")
[1] ": Hornets - Mathiang, Paige (G League Team - two-way player), Zeller (Injury/Illness - left knee surgery)\r\nPoints"
```

So, why doesn't it work when I target `\r\nEjections\r\n` as my endpoint? The only difference I can see is that `\r\n` both precedes and succeeds `Ejections`, whereas `\r\n` only precedes `Points`. I've tried to account for the additional `\r\n` like so:

```
> techs <- str_extract(txt[1], "(?<=\\bTechnical).+?.(\\\r\nEjections\r\n)")
> techs
[1] NA
```

But, that still doesn't work. What is this `\r\n` that's all over the place, and how do I account for it? I acquired this character string from a PDF like so:

```
library(pdftools)
> download.file("http://www.nba.com/data/html/nbacom/2017/gameinfo/20180117/0021700653_Book.pdf", "mydf", mode = "wb")
trying URL 'http://www.nba.com/data/html/nbacom/2017/gameinfo/20180117/0021700653_Book.pdf'
Content type 'application/pdf' length unknown
downloaded 308 KB

> txt <- pdf_text("mydf")
> txt[1]
[1] "NATIONAL BASKETBALL ASSOCIATION                                                                                                  OFFICIAL SCORER'S REPORT\r\n                                                                                                                                                      FINAL BOX\r\nWednesday, January 17, 2018 Spectrum Center, Charlotte, NC\r\nOfficials: #15 Zach Zarba, #11 Derrick Collins, #12 CJ Washington\r\n                                                                                                                                                Game Duration: 2:14\r\n                                                                                                                                                 Attendance: 11528\r\nVISITOR: Washington Wizards (25-20)\r\n                                                    POS       MIN         FG FGA 3P 3PA FT FTA OR DR TOT A PF ST                                 TO  BS    +/- PTS\r\n22  Otto Porter Jr.                                   F      22:45         2      6      1       3        1       2       0    2    2  2 0 0      0   0   -24   6\r\n 5  Markieff Morris                                   F      15:26         1      5      0       2        0       0       0    5    5  1 4 0      1   0   -10   2\r\n13  Marcin Gortat                                     C      19:42         0      3      0       0        0       2       3    5    8  1 2 2      0   0   -23   0\r\n 3  Bradley Beal                                      G      27:43        10 19          4       6        2       2       1    2    3  2 1 0      5   1   -14   26\r\n 2  John Wall                                         G      24:20         5     11      2       2        0       0       0    2    2  9 2 0      3   2   -20   12\r\n30  Mike Scott                                               25:13 7             10      2       2        2       2       0    2    2  3  3   1 0     0    -8   18\r\n12  Kelly Oubre Jr.                                          26:32 5              9      3       5        3       4       0    5    5  0  4   0 3     0     3   16\r\n28  Ian Mahinmi                                              08:47 1              2      0       0        2       2       0    1    1  2  1   0 0     1    -1   4\r\n31  Tomas Satoransky                                         25:49 2              3      0       0        2       2       1    2    3  7  1   0 1     0   -13   6\r\n20  Jodie Meeks                                              20:17 2              3      1       2        2       3       1    4    5  0  0   0 2     0   -10   7\r\n14  Jason Smith                                              13:50 4              8      0       0        2       2       1    2    3  3  5   0 1     2     0   10\r\n 1  Chris McCullough                                         06:48 1              3      0       1        0       0       0    1    1  0  0   0 0     1    -1   2\r\n 8  Tim Frazier                                              02:48 0              0      0       0        0       2       0    0    0  1  0   0 0     0     1   0\r\n                                                            240:00 40            82     13      23       16      23       7   33   40 31 23   3 16    7   -24  109\r\n                                                                           48.8%         56.5%             69.6%           TM REB: 7     TOT TO: 16 (20 PTS)\r\nHOME: CHARLOTTE HORNETS (18-25)\r\n                                                    POS       MIN         FG FGA 3P 3PA FT FTA OR DR TOT A PF ST                                 TO  BS    +/- PTS\r\n14  Michael Kidd-Gilchrist                            F      22:59         8     11      0       0        5       6       0    4    4  2 1 3      0   0    26   21\r\n 2  Marvin Williams                                   F      21:38         4      7      3       4        1       1       1    2    3  1 0 0      1   0    25   12\r\n12  Dwight Howard                                     C      28:54         7     13      0       0        4       5       3   12 15 2 2 2         2   2    17   18\r\n 5  Nicolas Batum                                     G      26:00         4      8      2       4        1       2       0    3    3  4 1 1      2   0    17   11\r\n15  Kemba Walker                                      G      28:48         6     15      4       8        3       3       1    2    3  7 1 0      1   1    14   19\r\n 3  Jeremy Lamb                                              21:02 7              9      2       2        0       0       3    0    3  0  4   0   0   1    -4   16\r\n44  Frank Kaminsky                                           23:36 6             14      1       4        1       1       0    2    2  2  1   1   0   0    -5   14\r\n10  Michael Carter-Williams                                  15:12 0              2      0       1        3       4       0    3    3  5  2   0   0   1     8   3\r\n 8  Johnny O'Bryant III                                      19:07 2              6      1       2        2       2       3    3    6  1  1   1   2   0     7   7\r\n21  Treveon Graham                                           22:00 3              6      1       2        2       2       2    2    4  1  4   1   1   0     7   9\r\n 1  Malik Monk                                               03:59 1              5      1       3        0       0       0    1    1  1  0   1   0   0     2   3\r\n 7  Dwayne Bacon                                             03:59 0              2      0       1        0       0       0    0    0  0  0   0   0   0     2   0\r\n32  Julyan Stone                                             02:46 0              0      0       0        0       0       0    2    2  1  1   0   0   0     4   0\r\n                                                            240:00 48            98     15      31       22      26      13   36   49 27 18  10   9   5    24  133\r\n                                                                             49%         48.4%             84.6%           TM REB: 7     TOT TO: 10 (15 PTS)\r\nSCORE BY PERIOD 1                    2       3       4     FINAL\r\n               Wizards 36           25      18      30        109\r\n            HORNETS 38              39      25      31        133\r\nInactive: Wizards - Mac (Injury/Illness - left achilles surgery), Robinson (G League Team - two-way player)\r\nInactive: Hornets - Mathiang, Paige (G League Team - two-way player), Zeller (Injury/Illness - left knee surgery)\r\nPoints in the Paint: Wizards 30 (15/27), HORNETS 50 (25/48)                                Biggest Lead: Wizards 2, HORNETS 28\r\n2nd Chance Points: Wizards 9 (4/7), HORNETS 21 (6/12)                                      Lead Changes: 2\r\nFast Break Points: Wizards 16 (6/8), HORNETS 10 (5/8)                                      Times Tied: 5\r\nTechnical fouls - Individual\r\nWizards (3): Wall 4:16 1st , Brooks 6:49 2nd , Frazier 4:00 4th\r\nHORNETS (2): Kidd-Gilchrist 3:08 2nd , Carter-Williams 4:00 4th\r\nTechnical fouls - Defensive Three Seconds\r\nWizards (0) : NONE\r\nHORNETS (1) : Howard 2:27 1st\r\nEjections\r\nWizards (1): Frazier 4:00 4th\r\nHORNETS (1): Carter-Williams 4:00 4th\r\nMEMO: Ejected for excessive communication and contact during stoppage in play.\r\nMEMO: Ejected for excessive communication and contact during stoppage in play.\r\n                                                         Copyright (c ) 2017-2018 NBA Properties, INC. All Rights Reserved\r\n"
```

Obviously, the PDF does not show `\r\n`s in its text. Were they inserted upon conversion? Is there a way to convert without them? Or, is there a simple-enough way to work with them? Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**

It does not appear that adding `\\` to `\\\r\n` makes a difference.

```
> techs <- str_extract(txt[1], "(?<=\\bTechnical).+?.(\\\r\n)")
> techs
[1] " fouls - Individual\r\n"
> techs <- str_extract(txt[1], "(?<=\\bTechnical).+?.(\\\r\nEjections)")
> techs
[1] NA
> techs <- str_extract(txt[1], "(?<=\\bTechnical).+?.(\\\r\nEjections\r\n)")
> techs
[1] NA
> techs <- str_extract(txt[1], "(?<=\\bTechnical).+?.(\\\r\nEjections\\\r\n)")
> techs
[1] NA
> techs <- str_extract(txt[1], "(?<=\\bTechnical).+?.(\\\r\nEjections\\\r\\\n)")
> techs
[1] NA
> techs <- str_extract(txt[1], "(?<=\\bTechnical).+?.(\\\r\\\nEjections\\\r\\\n)")
> techs
[1] NA
> techs <- str_extract(txt[1], "(?<=\\bTechnical).+?.(\\\r\\\nEjections\\\r\n)")
> techs
[1] NA
> techs <- str_extract(txt[1], "(?<=\\bTechnical).+?.(\\\r\\\nEjections\r\n)")
> techs
[1] NA
> techs <- str_extract(txt[1], "(?<=\\bTechnical).+?.(\\\r\\\nEjections)")
> techs
[1] NA
```

Am I doing it right?

Comment: I notice that you used `\\\r\n`. Maybe the slashes should be one way or the other. Like `\\\r\\\n`.

Comment: In R you need to use two \ characters.  Because \ is an escape character in r.  So to select "\n" You need `\\\n`